# CSS code is not working with chrome and Firefox but IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, visual-studio-2012

I am working with Visual studio 2012, Created a masterpage for my website.
all other pages are working fine but only one page driving me crazy.

```
.aboutus
{ margin: auto;
font-family: 'Bookman Old Style';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 100;
max-height:700px;
overflow:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;}

.aboutus h1, .aboutus h2, .aboutus h3
{
    color:blue;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight: 500;}
```

IF I use this css class it work fine with IE but nothings shows up in Chrome or mozilla.
even if I delete contants from .aboutus css class it still have the same problem.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<div class="aboutus">
<h1>About us…</h1>
<p>Regional Automotive was started in 1994 at it’s current location in Ottawa 
    as a sister c..........
 </div></asp:Content>
```

My asp:Content is from masterpage

```
<div class="main-content">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </div>
```

I use this in my masterpage so I dont have to write the same thing again and again for every page

```
.main-content
{display:block;
background-color:transparent;
min-height: 700px;
max-height:700px;
margin-left:2px;
margin-top:68px;}
```

may be this thing causing a problem.

Comment: I suspect there is another problem at play here, what you posted seems to work fine for me in all browsers.  Is it possible another part of your code is the cause?  http://jsfiddle.net/g5CFC/

Comment: @Lochemage - your fiddle link is hosed, but +1 for creating it...

Comment: I guess .main-content may be a cause for this problem but I dont understand why

Answer (score 0):

I tried copy your code and use at my PC. Workst fine in Opera, Chrome, IE.

Do you have latest version of browsers? You can try write css file line by line and try to discover which line do the problem